# I want to change setting "Screen Blank" under "Power" from 15 minutes (default max) to 60 minutes

Tags: 22.04, system-settings

I want my screen to turn off after being inactive for 60 minutes, but the longest time I can do that for is 15 (by default.)
So can I edit settings to change this value to 60 so it turns off after 60 minutes?
I don't want to choose "Never" bc then it could burn into my screen if I accidentally leave it open for 8+ hours, nor do I want to download/use an application to accompish this.
Anyone have an idea of how I could do this?

Comment: Yes, this also answered it, Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can forcibly set the screen blank setting to 1 hour with the following command:

```bash
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.session idle-delay 3600
```

This causes a "1 hour" item to show up in the dropdown, but the dropdown will be glitched to always say "Never". It should theoretically still work though.